# How to wrap Text for labels in chartjs canvas with angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, charts

I am trying with chartjs canvas in angular 4.

After rendering the labels and other data, in chart few labels are not visible. While I zoom out the screen, I can see all the labels. In the attached image, all question mark labels are not visible.
I am trying out with wrap text in axis label, but not sure how and where should I mention wrap text.

I'll be thankful if you can help me out.
Let me know if you need any code.

[image]